# How to fix 404 page error on theme

Tags: 404-error

I am using the MidMo Clean theme and for some reason the 404 error page isn't working.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/wpversec/public_html/UXJobsLA.com/wp-content/themes/clean-home/404.php on line 14

http://uxjobsla.com/error

Short of me disabling all my plugins and re-installing a out of the box version of the theme, anyone have any ideas please? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Eileen, I missed the accept check mark entirely and went back to check mark some of the great answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you're problem is the quotes in the href inside your function. Try escaping them like this and it should be fixed.

```
    <p><?php _e("Sorry but, you are looking for something that isn't here. <br /><br />
Looking for more web developer jobs, please visit our sister site: <a href=\"http://LAMPjobsLA.com\">LAMPjobsLA.com</a>", 'cleanhome') ;?></p>
```